# How does table partition and mapping work?

Tags: database, database-design, query-performance

I have a database with one critical table which is widely used and queried. The lifetime of the data in this table is divided in two stages: `Table1` and `Table1_Hist`, this way once the User has finished his work then the record is passed from `Table1` to `Table1_Hist` for consultation and reports.

The structure of `Table1` is

```
ID (Long) KEY,
Priority (INT)
val1 (VARBINARY(XXXX))
val2 (VARNINARY(XXXX))
```

This table is filled with millions of records per month and the records passed to `Table1_Hist` are made in no specific order, this means that `User1` may insert a record in `Table1` today and finish working with it today too, but `User2` may insert a similar record in `Table1` and finish working with it the next week or month or in 3 months.

The issue arises when the `Table1_Hist` starts to grow to the point of affecting the performance of the queries to this table. I had in mind to split this table in `Table1_Hist_1`, `Table1_Hist_2`... `Table1_Hist_n` and create an `ID` table Map where I can register the range of `IDs` stored on each table. For example, I may have a map saying that in `Table1_Hist_1` are stored the `IDs` from 1 to 10M and so on, **but** as I said before, there is no order in time in which the records are inserted in these historical tables, hence I may have a Map from 1 to 10 pointing to table `Table1_Hist_1` and also have a record ID=3 in `Table1_Hist_2`, just because the ID=3 was finished 2 months later and stored in the following table.

So, anyone knows about an efficient approach to split a table in multiple tables with their respective mapping?

Comment: Which rdbms are you using?

Comment: @twoleggedhorse applies to any.